# Asserting span class with phpunit

Tags: css, phpunit

How would I go about asserting content within a span class
for example:

```
<span class="input-error-message">Invalid email or password</span>
```

I want to assert that the text **Invalid email or password** is displayed on the page?

Lost

Comment: Can you explain this in a different way? I'm not totally sure what you're asking.

Comment: `$this->assertContains('Invalid email or password', $yourHtml)` - as for how you construct your test to get the `$yourHtml` value, we can't really help you with the amount of background information you've given us